# Garbage Collector not freeing "trash memory" as it should in an Android application

Tags: java, android, performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Hello!

I'm a beginner Java and Android developer and I've been having trouble lately dealing with my app's memory management. I will break this text into sections, in order to make it clearer and readable.

### A brief description of my app

It's a game that consists of several stages (levels). Each stage has a starting point for the player and an exit, which leads the player to the next stage. Each stage has its own set of obstacles. Currently, when the player reaches the final stage (I've only created 4 so far) he/she automatically goes back to the first stage (level 1).

An abstract class called *GameObject* (extends *Android.View*) defines the base structure and behaviour for the player and all the other objects (obstacles, etc) present in the game. All the objects (that are, essentially, views) are drawn in a custom view created by me (extends FrameLayout). The game logic and the game loop is handled by a side thread (gameThread). The stages are created by retrieving metadata from xml files.

### The problem

Besides all the possible memory leaks on my code (all of which I've been working hard to find and solve), there is a strange phenomenon related to the garbage collector happening. Instead of describing it with words and risk getting you confused, I will use images. As Confucius said, "An image is worth a thousand words". Well, in this case, I've just saved you from reading 150,000 words, since my GIF below has 150 frames.

[image: Stage 1 when firstly loaded. The total memory allocation of the app is 85mb.]
[image: Stage 1 when loaded for the second time. The total memory allocation of the app is 130mb. After I forcefully perform 2 garbage collections (using Android Profiler), the memory goes back to 85mb.]

**Description:** the first image represents my app's memory usage when the "stage 1" is first loaded. The second image (GIF) firstly represents my app's memory usage timeline when the "stage 1" is loaded for the second time (this happens, as described earlier, when the player beat the last stage) and is followed by four *garbage collections* forcefully initiated by me.

As you might have noticed, there is a huge difference (almost 50MB) in the memory usage between the two situations. When the "Stage 1" is firstly loaded, when the game starts, the app is using 85MB of memory. When the same stage is loaded for the second time, a little bit later, the memory usage is already at 130MB! That's probably due to some bad coding on my part and I'm not here because of this. Have you noticed how, after I forcefully performed 2 (actually 4, but only the first 2 mattered) garbage collections, the memory usage went back to it's "normal state" (the same memory usage as when the stage was firstly loaded)? **That's the weird phenomenon I was talking about**.

### The question

If the *garbage collector* is supposed to remove from memory objects that are no long being referenced (or, at least, have only *weak references*), **why is the "trash memory" that you saw above being removed only when I forcefully call the *GC* and not on the *GC's* normal executions?** I mean, if the *garbage collection* manually initiated by me could remove this "thrash", then the normal *GC's* executions would be able to remove it as well. Why isn't it happening?

I've even tried to call *System.gc()* when the stages are being switched, but, even though the *garbage collection* happens, this "thrash" memory isn't removed like when I manually perform the *GC*. Am I missing something important about how the *garbage collector* works or about how Android implements it?

### Final considerations

I've spent days searching, studying and making modifications on my code but I could not find out why this is happening. StackOverflow is my last resort. Thank you!

**NOTE:** I was going to post some possibly relevant part of my app's source code, but since the question is already too long I will stop here. If you feel the need to check some of the code, just let me know and I will edit this question.

**What I have already read:**

[How to force garbage collection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/how-to-force-garbage-collection-in-java)

[Garbage collector in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117429/garbage-collector-in-android)

[Java Garbage Collection Basics by Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

[Android Memory Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview)

[Memory Leak Patterns in Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/memory-leak-patterns-in-android-4741a7fcb570)

[Avoiding Memory Leaks in Android](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

[Manage your app's memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory)

[What you need to know about Android app memory leaks](https://techbeacon.com/what-you-need-know-about-android-app-memory-leaks)

 [View the Java heap and memory allocations with Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler)

[LeakCanary (memory leak detection library for Android and Java)](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)

[Android Memory Leak and Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635184/android-memory-leak-and-garbage-collection)

[Generic Android Garbage Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035593/generic-android-garbage-collection)

[How to clear dynamically created view from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949047/how-to-clear-dynamically-created-view-from-memory)

[How References Work in Android and Java](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83)

[Java Garbage Collector - Not running normally at regular intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309105/java-garbage-collector-not-running-normally-at-regular-intervals)

[Garbage Collection in android (Done manually)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177802/garbage-collection-in-android-done-manually)

... and more I couldn't find again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Garbage collection is complicated, and different platforms implement it differently.  Indeed, different *versions* of the same platform implement garbage collection differently.  (And more ... )

A typical modern collector is based on the observation that *most* objects die young; i.e. they become unreachable soon after they are created.  The heap is then divided into two or more "spaces"; e.g. a "young" space and an "old" space.

- The "young" space is where new objects are created, and it is collected frequently.  The "young" space tends to be smaller, and a "young" collection happens quickly.
- The "old" space is where long-lived objects end up, and it is collected infrequently.  On "old" space collection tends to be more expensive.  (For various reasons.)
- Object that survive a number of GC cycles in the "new" space get "tenured"; i.e they are moved to the "old" space.
- Occasionally we may find that we need to collect the new and old spaces at the same time.  This is called a full collection.  A full GC is the most expensive, and typically "stops the world" for a relatively long time.

(There are all sorts of other clever and complex things ... which I won't go into.)

---

Your question is why doesn't the space usage drop significantly until you call `System.gc()`.

The answer is basically that this is the *efficient* way to do things.

The real goal of collection is not to free as much memory all of the time.  Rather, the goal is to ensure that there is enough free memory when it is needed, and to do this either with minimum CPU overheads or a minimum of GC pauses.

So in normal operation, the GC will behave as above: do frequent "new" space collections and less frequent "old" space collections.   And the collections
will run "as required".

But when you call `System.gc()` the JVM will *typically* try to get back as much memory as possible.  That means it does a "full gc".

Now I think you said it takes a couple of `System.gc()` calls to make a real difference, that could be related to use of `finalize` methods or `Reference` objects or similar.  It turns out that finalizable objects and `Reference` are processed after the main GC has finished by a background thread.  The objects are only actually in a state where they can be collected and deleted *after* that.  So another GC is needed to finally get rid of them.

Finally, there is the issue of the overall heap size.  Most VMs request memory from the host operating system when the heap is too small, but are reluctant to give it back.  The Oracle collectors note the free space ratio at the end of successive "full" collections.  They only reduce the overall size of the heap if the free space ratio is "too high" after a number of GC cycles.  There are a number of reasons that the Oracle GCs take this approach:

1. Typical modern GCs work most efficiently when the ratio of garbage to non-garbage objects is high.  So keeping the heap large aids efficiency.
2. There is a good chance that the application's memory requirement will grow again.  But the GC needs to run to detect that.
3. A JVM repeatedly giving memory back to the OS and and re-requesting it is potentially disruptive for the OS virtual memory algorithms.
4. It is problematic if the OS is short of memory resources; e.g. JVM: "I don't need this memory. Have it back", OS: "Thanks", JVM: "Oh ... I need it again!", OS: "Nope", JVM: "OOME".

Assuming that the Android collector works the same way, that is another explanation for why you had to run `System.gc()` multiple times to get the heap size to shrink.

---

And before you start adding `System.gc()` calls to your code, read [Why is it bad practice to call System.gc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Stephen! This really helped me better understand _garbage collection_. However, I think I didn't explain very well the situation. The graphs you can see in my question are displayed by a tool from the IDE _Android Studio_ called _Android Profiler_. The drop in the memory usage (according to the graphs) only happens when I click (at least twice) the button "Force Garbage Collection", available in that tool. When I tried to reproduce this programmatically, calling _System.gc()_, the memory usage didn't drop, even though the graph showed that a GC had occurred.

Comment: Well, given your answer, I'm starting to suspect that this whole thing doesn't necessarily have to do with the _garbage collection_ process itself, but rather with how _Android Profiler_ gets and displays the information about the memory usage.

Comment: What I was trying to explain was that what you are seeing is normal behavior.  You shouldn't *expect* the heap / space sizes to drop under normal operation unless the application is modal.

Comment: I see. Well, I will stop worrying about this, then. Thank you again!

Comment: One of the best Q&As I've seen on SO. Why doesn't this have 1000 upvotes?

Answer (score -2):

I got the same problem on my app, I seen you have understood the GC, try to watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcPuWY0wn3w) on why the GC is needed. try to add this code to your app class (the java file of the app, like each java file for each activity) and add this code under the Override of the "onCreate" (the code is in kotlin)

here is the hole class:

```
open class _appName_() : Application(){
    private var appKilled = false
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        thread {
            while (!appKilled){
                Thread.sleep(6000)
                System.runFinalization()
                Runtime.getRuntime().gc()
                System.gc()
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate()
        appKilled = true
    }
}
```

this bit of code make that every 6 sec GC is called

Comment: This is a terrible idea; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc

Comment: this is very nice to say... you can say the same thing but nicer

Comment: How do you call something a terrible idea nicely?  While also expressing that it is a terrible idea?  I am not criticizing you personally, but this answer is really bad advice.  And it is important that other people realize this.  If someone *really* needs to forcibly run the GC like this, then either there is a significant design problem in their app ... or they have chosen the wrong programming language.

Comment: That was the nice way! It's nothing compared to some other comments I've seen. ...